# How to change a UI Image that has an animator attached to it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to update my weapon icon UI image when a new weapon is selected.

I could create a public array of images and load them in inspector and then changing the Image from script is as simple as

> GetComponent().sprite = someSprite;

But I have an animator attached to the image of each icon that animates the images. How would I change the animator of each image along with its sprite?

This is the Image component along with animator component. I need to change both via script. Any idea how I could achieve this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: how does the `Animator` "animate the image"?

Comment: its a sprite sheet animator that changes the sprite or image component at a certain rate

Comment: well as soon as there is any keyframe set for a certain property you can't change it otherwise ... the animator will always overrule any changes made during runtime  since the [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html#AnimationUpdateLoop) is done after the normal `Update`. If you want to set it from script try doing it in `LateUpdate` or simply temporarely disable the animator component